# Dependent parameters or type-level functions with proofs?

Tags: idris, dependent-type, proof-of-correctness

I'm deciding between parametrising my type by a `Vect r Nat` and `List Nat`. At first, I thought that with the former I can constrain the vector length like

```
foo : Vect m Nat -> Vect m Nat -> Vect (2 * m) Nat
```

and this makes `Vect` more powerful, but then I realised I can do the same, albeit more verbosely, with lists and proofs

```
foo : (x : List Nat) -> (y : List Nat)
      -> {auto _ : length x = length y} -> List (2 * length x) Nat
```

Now I'm wondering if this is generally true. Is parametrising with values any different to using type-level functions with proofs?